# Why am I getting a contentRootPath null exception when attempting to add a database migration in entityframework core?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core class library that is the data access layer for multiple web applications. I am using Entity Framework Core 1.1, but I'm having trouble with migrations through PMC. My initial migration worked successfully, but after updating the database and re-launching VS 2017 I get a null exception on the contentRootPath argument when attempting to migrate. I may have made some changes to the project after my successful migration, but I don't remember what they were. This is the error and stack trace:

```
Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework 6.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: contentRootPath
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations..ctor(IOperationReporter reporter, Assembly assembly, Assembly startupAssembly, String environment, String projectDir, String contentRootPath, String rootNamespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<.ctor>b__4()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

There is no config file in my migrations directory, and I can't find anything related in the DbContext class. Has anyone else ran into this issue, or know what is causing it?

SqlDbContext class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using DataLayer.Models.User;

namespace DataLayer.Context 
{
  public class SqlDbContext : DbContext
  {
      public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

      protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      {
          optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(MyDbConfig.SqlConnectionString);   
      }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
              .Ignore(m => m.FullName);

          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you using both EF6 and EFC?

Comment: No, I am not using EF6, but it is in the project.

Comment: I edited your tags... to only show EFC.  Can you show us your references? Startup.cs and appsettings.json

Comment: It's in a Class Library, so there is no Startup.cs or appsettings.json files. I am just storing my connection string in a static class, along with connection strings to other databases that I am accessing. I updated the code snipped with my references. And my mistake before, I meant that EF6 is in the solution, not the project.

Comment: I just looked at my Nuget packages, and for some reason my EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package was a pre-release version (2.0.0). I just downgraded to 1.1.1, and now migrations are working again. Not sure why it updated to an unstable version, but it's working now. Thanks anyway for you help!

Comment: probably accidental upgrade...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was due to the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package being pre-release version 2.0.0, which is not currently a stable version. Downgrading to 1.1.1 fixed the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not mean 1.0.1?

Comment: There is no 1.1.1 version though

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in the past and here is the fix:

First, make sure that the version of the SDK you are using is 2.1.200 as you are under Core 1.1 and put this on your global.json:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.200"
  }
}
```

Add reference on your .csproj to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` so you will have:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design"
                      Version="1.1.6"
                       PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
     <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet"
                            Version="1.1.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
```