# Entity framework core 1.1.2 migration exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am getting following strange exceptions.

I already saw following thread discussing about downgrading Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to 1.1.1 which I already did, but still these exceptions are appearing.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: contentRootPath
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations..ctor(IOperationReporter reporter, Assembly assembly, Assembly startupAssembly, String environment, String projectDir, String contentRootPath, String rootNamespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<.ctor>b__4()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

Can any body help in this regard.

Comment: Try the solution I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690559/why-am-i-getting-a-contentrootpath-null-exception-when-attempting-to-add-a-datab/53420306#53420306 I hope that it will helps you!

Answer (score 2):

Just to note in retrospect that I got this error while trying to run a dotnet CLI command. The problem I found was that the CLI environment was defaulting to use the .NET Core 2.0 version of the *dotnet* and *ef* commands but I needed to use the .NET Core 1.1 version because that was what the package versions were built against.

I discovered (by running *dotnet --info*) that there was more than one version of .NET Core SDK installed on the environment and the Path pointed to the latest by default. To use the older version I added a **global.json** file in the solution root with the specific version number. e.g.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.1.11"
  }
}
```

and everything worked.

Comment: My version was 2.0.0, differs with sdks installed I think.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your versions align.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.5" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet"
                          Version="1.1.5" />
</ItemGroup>
```